# In Cordova android platform, which one is app module

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

In Cordova Android platform, by default there are two modules i.e. **CordovaLib** and **android**, which one is app module.

Comment: `android` is yours

Comment: @MaximShoustin, Yes but I do not have much idea about android as hybrid app dev., and I'm trying to add some modules and dependencies into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*build.gradle* with *Module: android* is app(main) module

[find the snap of Android-Studio highlighting module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MISXf.png)